# How can I properly check if the URL contains request parameters in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

This is the URL I use for signin page without any request parameters.

```
http://localhost:8080/signin
```

This is the URL for signin page with bad credentials error,

```
http://localhost:8080/signin?param.error=bad_credentials
```

Now I check for `param.error` like below,

```
<div class="error" th:if="${(param.error != null) and (param.error[0] == 'bad_credentials')}">
```

When I load the signin page I get a SpringEL exception,

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(param.error != null) and (param.error[0] == 'bad_credentials')"
```

I think since there are no request parameters when I load the signin page it cant find `param.error`.

How can I properly check if the URL contains request parameters?

Comment: try th:if="${param.error} and ${param.error[0] == 'bad_credentials'}"

Comment: I didn't notice you actually called your param 'param.error'. Try making request to http://localhost:8080/signin?error=bad_credentials.

Answer (score 6):

This is tricky. In the documentation you are encouraged to use:

```
${param.containsKey('foo')}
```

But it doesn't work and when you look at the source of this class it's suddenly clear:

```
@Override
public boolean containsKey(final Object key) {
    return true;
}
```

I end up with:

```
${param.keySet().contains('foo')}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this :) Maybe it's a little ugly way to get param, but it works.

```
<div th:with="myMap=${#ctx.requestParameters}">
      <span th:if="${#maps.containsKey(myMap, 'param')}" th:text="${'requestParam: ' + #ctx.requestParameters.get('param')[0]}"></span>
</div>
```

My address: `http://localhost:8080/thvsjsp/subscribeth?param=something`

Output: `requestParam: something`

[Useful chapter in manual](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#base-objects)

HTH

**EDIT:**

Here is much better way:

```
<span th:if="${param.abc != null}" th:text="${'requestParam: ' + param.abc[0]}"></span>
```

Request param is `String[]` and that's why we need to use `[0]`

[Here more about it](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Request-parameter-td3325136.html)

Comment: The "if" can be simplified even further: `th:if="${param.abc}"`